# Optimize multiple HTML5 Videos

Tags: html, performance, video, html5-video, autoplay

I have multiple HTML5 videos on a webpage I am creating. They autoplay and loop like gifs.

However, the page barely loads with the 6 or so 15 sec videos. Is there a way to optimize these videos so that the page loads them and itself faster?

EDIT:

Most Buzzfeed pages have dozens of video "gifs" on one page and they load fine. I'm wondering how I can do this? Currently the browser becomes overloaded.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I'm making a 9gag-like site. They also mimic gif with HTML5 video. Did you find the solution yet?

Comment: Don't use pre-load, Don't play until the video is on screen, use a video cdn to host

Comment: 'a video cdn to host' - sorry I don't understand this part. Actually, i'm stuck with in-view to play a HTML video.

Answer (score 0):

Most devices have optimised hardware and software to play videos, to reduce CPU and preserve battery life for example.

Once you ask the device to play multiple videos at the same time you start to overload any optimal paths and playback may fall back to software to do all the heavy lifting.

One way round this, if your particular application will work with the approach, is to combine the videos on the server side into a single video.

You can still make this look like separate videos, by hiding the main controls and adding overlays with individual buttons over the relevant area.

If this does not work for you, then making the videos as low bandwidth and as short as possible will help. If you can avoid autoplaying this will obviously make a big difference also.

As a note, Buzzfeed does have multiple videos on a page but they do not auto play when I look at their pages, which means all they have to download and display is the thumbnail (maybe we are looking at different pages - if you have an example page that autoplays multiple videos, can you give a link?_.

Comment: Thanks so much for this answer. The major issue is that I do want the videos to autoplay. They are supposed to mimic GIFs. On buzzfeed articles they sometimes have articles with 40+ autoplaying "GIFS". One example is ["43 Funniest Gifs" post](https://www.buzzfeed.com/richardhjames/are-these-the-funniest-gifs-of-all-time)

Comment: If you scroll down quickly I think you'll find that it is only the ones on the part of the page in view and maybe the next one or two which are actually playing - the rest are just ready to play when they are scrolled to. This is certainly what I see - let me know if you see it differently?